# Задержка перед показом layout-a меню

Tags: android, android-layout

При открытии overflow-меню на какую-то долю секунды перед открытием становится виден просто пустой layout, и только после этого появляется само меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогичная ситуация происходит и при закрытии этого overflow-меню - сначала пропадает layout с текстом меню, но ещё на долю секунды виден пустой layout:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создание этого меню вроде бы стандартно:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_cp:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_used_libraries:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_help_and_feedback:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Почему тогда происходит эта задержка и как от неё избавиться?

Comment: Добавьте xml, похоже что тут идет анимация после раскрытия меню. Это какая-то либа или стандартные компоненты?

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko, нет, никакой анимации нет. И компоненты стандартные. xml добавлю чуть позже)

Comment: Это стандартное поведение, причем на разных девайсах может отличаться. Вы вопрос, то задайте, вам что нужно сделать?

Comment: все же здесь явно видно анимацию. Даже если вы сами не назначали ее, есть системные анимации. Вы можете убедится в этом, отключив анимации в настройках "для разработчика". Самое очевидное - оставить все как есть, но если это вас категорически не устраивает, нужно думать, как программно отключить такую анимацию в своем приложении

Comment: @pavlofff, да, действительно, при отключении анимации в настройках "для разработчика" задержка исчезает. Так, получается, эта задержка - это нормальное поведение, а не лаг, который нужно исправлять?

Comment: да, так и есть.